# Angular template project created through VS 2017 all of sudden throws failed to load resource : the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I am built my project using VS 2017 angular template and it was running fine all these days. No clue what I changed or if the packages got auto updated when I run the project now it starts to log error in chrome console as Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) for all the template html files and never loads the UI.

Any help much appreciated.

My npm version is 5.6.0

and node version is 9.5.0

angular version is 4.2.5

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Do you have your components in an app folder? Have you changed the .angular-cli.json file? What does the `app` section of that file contain?

Comment: Yes, I've components in app folder. Where can I find .angular-cli.json file?

Comment: in the root of your AngularCLI project - the folder is usually named the same as your project name.

Comment: I cannot find any file with name of .angular-cli.json in the root of project file.

Comment: That is likely your issue. Create a new Angular project in a new folder  using the cli. You'll find the default version of the file there. Try to copy that file to your current project and see what happens.

Comment: I've created a new project with vs 2017 angular template and it even doesnt create this file. Still the new project is running fine.

Comment: Wait...what? The question states "Angular CLI project created through VS. So did you use a template or did you use the CLI?

Comment: My apologies, I've used template. I've updated the question title now but I've mentioned it correctly in the description.

Comment: Can't help. I highly recommend you consider using the AngularCLI as your only tool for scaffolding Angular apps. You'll find it much easier to find help.